# TypeError: __init__() takes at least 3 arguments (1 given)

Tags: python, user-interface, wxpython, wxformbuilder

This is my code for a GUI :

```
import wx
import os.path


class MainWindow(wx.Frame):
    #def __init__(self, filename=''):
        #super(MainWindow, self).__init__(None, size=(800,600))
    def __init__(self, parent, title, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow,self).__init__(parent, title = title, size = (800,600))
        wx.Frame.__init__ ( self, parent, id = wx.ID_ANY, title = wx.EmptyString, pos =  wx.DefaultPosition, size = wx.Size( 800,608 ), style = wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE|wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL )
        self.SetSizeHintsSz( wx.DefaultSize, wx.DefaultSize )
        grid = wx.GridSizer( 2, 2, 0, 0 )

        self.filename = filename
        self.dirname = '.'
        self.CreateInteriorWindowComponents()
        self.CreateExteriorWindowComponents()

    def CreateInteriorWindowComponents(self):


        staticbox = wx.StaticBoxSizer( wx.StaticBox( self, wx.ID_ANY, u"Enter text" ), wx.VERTICAL )
        staticbox.Add( self.m_textCtrl1, 0, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 5 )
        self.m_textCtrl1 = wx.TextCtrl( self, wx.ID_ANY, wx.EmptyString, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.Size( -1,250 ), wx.TE_MULTILINE)
        self.m_textCtrl1.SetMaxLength(10000)

        self.Submit = wx.Button( self, wx.ID_ANY, u"Submit", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
        staticbox.Add( self.Submit, 0, wx.ALL, 5 )

    def CreateExteriorWindowComponents(self):
        ''' Create "exterior" window components, such as menu and status
            bar. '''
        self.CreateMenu()
        self.CreateStatusBar()
        self.SetTitle()

    def CreateMenu(self):
        fileMenu = wx.Menu()
        for id, label, helpText, handler in \
            [(wx.ID_ABOUT, '&About', 'Storyteller 1.0 -',
                self.OnAbout),
             (wx.ID_OPEN, '&Open', 'Open a new file', self.OnOpen),
             (wx.ID_SAVE, '&Save', 'Save the current file', self.OnSave),
             (wx.ID_SAVEAS, 'Save &As', 'Save the file under a different name',
                self.OnSaveAs),
             (None, None, None, None),
             (wx.ID_EXIT, 'E&xit', 'Terminate the program', self.OnExit)]:
            if id == None:
                fileMenu.AppendSeparator()
            else:
                item = fileMenu.Append(id, label, helpText)
                self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, handler, item)

        menuBar = wx.MenuBar()
        menuBar.Append(fileMenu, '&File') # Add the fileMenu to the MenuBar
        self.SetMenuBar(menuBar)  # Add the menuBar to the Frame

    def SetTitle(self):
        # MainWindow.SetTitle overrides wx.Frame.SetTitle, so we have to
        # call it using super:
        super(MainWindow, self).SetTitle('Editor %s'%self.filename)


    # Helper methods:

    def defaultFileDialogOptions(self):
        ''' Return a dictionary with file dialog options that can be
            used in both the save file dialog as well as in the open
            file dialog. '''
        return dict(message='Choose a file', defaultDir=self.dirname,
                    wildcard='*.*')

    def askUserForFilename(self, **dialogOptions):
        dialog = wx.FileDialog(self, **dialogOptions)
        if dialog.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
            userProvidedFilename = True
            self.filename = dialog.GetFilename()
            self.dirname = dialog.GetDirectory()
            self.SetTitle() # Update the window title with the new filename
        else:
            userProvidedFilename = False
        dialog.Destroy()
        return userProvidedFilename

    # Event handlers:

    def OnAbout(self, event):
        dialog = wx.MessageDialog(self, 'A sample editor\n'
            'in wxPython', 'About Sample Editor', wx.OK)
        dialog.ShowModal()
        dialog.Destroy()

    def OnExit(self, event):
        self.Close()  # Close the main window.

    def OnSave(self, event):
        textfile = open(os.path.join(self.dirname, self.filename), 'w')
        textfile.write(self.control.GetValue())
        textfile.close()

    def OnOpen(self, event):
        if self.askUserForFilename(style=wx.OPEN,
                                   **self.defaultFileDialogOptions()):
            textfile = open(os.path.join(self.dirname, self.filename), 'r')
            self.control.SetValue(textfile.read())
            textfile.close()

    def OnSaveAs(self, event):
        if self.askUserForFilename(defaultFile=self.filename, style=wx.SAVE,
                                   **self.defaultFileDialogOptions()):
            self.OnSave(event)


app = wx.App()
frame = MainWindow()
frame.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

I'm getting the

```
TypeError:: __init__() takes at least 3 arguments (1 given)
```

on the 3rd last line `frame = MainWindow()`

How do I make sure the parameter list matches? I think I'm a little confused on passing self, parent or something.

Help please!

EDIT: @mhlester : I made the change you suggested but now I have a different error :

```
TypeError: in method 'new_Frame', expected argument 1 of type 'wxWindow *'
```

Infact this is what the complete text looks like :

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\BT\Desktop\BEt\gui2.py", line 115, in <module>
    frame = MainWindow(app,'Storyteller')
  File "C:\Users\BT\Desktop\BE\gui2.py", line 9, in __init__
    super(MainWindow,self).__init__(parent, title = title, size = (800,600))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\wx-3.0-msw\wx\_windows.py", line 580, in __init__
    _windows_.Frame_swiginit(self,_windows_.new_Frame(*args, **kwargs))
TypeError: in method 'new_Frame', expected argument 1 of type 'wxWindow *'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set up the init to accept 3 values and then you don't pass it anything. Because this frame will be a top level window, you can pass it a parent of None and some kind of title string:

```
frame = MainWindow(None, "test")
```

The next issue is that you try to use both initialization routines: the super and the regular. You can only use one or the other, but not both! I left the **super** one intact because it's shorter and commented out the latter. I also change **self.filename** to an empty string as "filename" is obviously not defined and I commented out the calls to build the other widgets as the code is incomplete.

```
import wx
import os.path


class MainWindow(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, title, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow,self).__init__(parent, title = title, size = (800,600))
        #wx.Frame.__init__ ( self, parent, id = wx.ID_ANY, title = wx.EmptyString, pos =  wx.DefaultPosition, size = wx.Size( 800,608 ), style = wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE|wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL )
        self.SetSizeHintsSz( wx.DefaultSize, wx.DefaultSize )
        grid = wx.GridSizer( 2, 2, 0, 0 )

        self.filename = ""
        self.dirname = '.'
        #self.CreateInteriorWindowComponents()
        #self.CreateExteriorWindowComponents()

    def CreateInteriorWindowComponents(self):


        staticbox = wx.StaticBoxSizer( wx.StaticBox( self, wx.ID_ANY, u"Enter text" ), wx.VERTICAL )
        staticbox.Add( self.m_textCtrl1, 0, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 5 )
        self.m_textCtrl1 = wx.TextCtrl( self, wx.ID_ANY, wx.EmptyString, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.Size( -1,250 ), wx.TE_MULTILINE)
        self.m_textCtrl1.SetMaxLength(10000)

        self.Submit = wx.Button( self, wx.ID_ANY, u"Submit", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
        staticbox.Add( self.Submit, 0, wx.ALL, 5 )

    def CreateExteriorWindowComponents(self):
        ''' Create "exterior" window components, such as menu and status
            bar. '''
        self.CreateMenu()
        self.CreateStatusBar()
        self.SetTitle()

    def CreateMenu(self):
        fileMenu = wx.Menu()
        for id, label, helpText, handler in \
            [(wx.ID_ABOUT, '&About', 'Storyteller 1.0 -',
                self.OnAbout),
             (wx.ID_OPEN, '&Open', 'Open a new file', self.OnOpen),
             (wx.ID_SAVE, '&Save', 'Save the current file', self.OnSave),
             (wx.ID_SAVEAS, 'Save &As', 'Save the file under a different name',
                self.OnSaveAs),
             (None, None, None, None),
             (wx.ID_EXIT, 'E&xit', 'Terminate the program', self.OnExit)]:
            if id == None:
                fileMenu.AppendSeparator()
            else:
                item = fileMenu.Append(id, label, helpText)
                self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, handler, item)

        menuBar = wx.MenuBar()
        menuBar.Append(fileMenu, '&File') # Add the fileMenu to the MenuBar
        self.SetMenuBar(menuBar)  # Add the menuBar to the Frame

    def SetTitle(self):
        # MainWindow.SetTitle overrides wx.Frame.SetTitle, so we have to
        # call it using super:
        super(MainWindow, self).SetTitle('Editor %s'%self.filename)


    # Helper methods:

    def defaultFileDialogOptions(self):
        ''' Return a dictionary with file dialog options that can be
            used in both the save file dialog as well as in the open
            file dialog. '''
        return dict(message='Choose a file', defaultDir=self.dirname,
                    wildcard='*.*')

    def askUserForFilename(self, **dialogOptions):
        dialog = wx.FileDialog(self, **dialogOptions)
        if dialog.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
            userProvidedFilename = True
            self.filename = dialog.GetFilename()
            self.dirname = dialog.GetDirectory()
            self.SetTitle() # Update the window title with the new filename
        else:
            userProvidedFilename = False
        dialog.Destroy()
        return userProvidedFilename

    # Event handlers:

    def OnAbout(self, event):
        dialog = wx.MessageDialog(self, 'A sample editor\n'
            'in wxPython', 'About Sample Editor', wx.OK)
        dialog.ShowModal()
        dialog.Destroy()

    def OnExit(self, event):
        self.Close()  # Close the main window.

    def OnSave(self, event):
        textfile = open(os.path.join(self.dirname, self.filename), 'w')
        textfile.write(self.control.GetValue())
        textfile.close()

    def OnOpen(self, event):
        if self.askUserForFilename(style=wx.OPEN,
                                   **self.defaultFileDialogOptions()):
            textfile = open(os.path.join(self.dirname, self.filename), 'r')
            self.control.SetValue(textfile.read())
            textfile.close()

    def OnSaveAs(self, event):
        if self.askUserForFilename(defaultFile=self.filename, style=wx.SAVE,
                                   **self.defaultFileDialogOptions()):
            self.OnSave(event)


app = wx.App()
frame = MainWindow(None, "test")
frame.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 0):

from the `MainWindow` declaration:

```
def __init__(self, parent, title, *args, **kwargs):
```

`self` passes automatically when you instantiate the class, but you need to pass `parent` and `title` to your `MainWindow()` call:

```
frame = MainWindow(app, 'Window Title') # i'm not sure if app is right for parent, but i assume it is
```

You can ignore the `*args` and `**kwargs` because reading through the `__init__` function they are not used at all...

Comment: @Bhavika it looks like I aws wrong about what `parent` needs to be. It says it needs to be another `wxWindow`. This is all I know, sorry. Maybe someone else has the answer to this new problem.

Comment: Yes I tried what you said, and it didnt work. See the solution below!

Comment: @Bhavika, Excellent! glad someone knew what they were doing.